# search for iPod artists starting with a letter

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmediaquery

Is there a way to use something like a wildcard character to search for all iPod artist names starting with a given letter, something like this:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artistNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"A*" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

MPMediaQuery *allArtistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];

[allArtistsQuery addFilterPredicate: artistNamePredicate];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPMediaPropertyPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPropertyPredicate_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) only supports the property value being equal to the predicate value (the default) or containing the predicate value, as noted in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPropertyPredicate_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaPredicateComparison).

That being said, an alternative is to use the *contains* comparison and then filter the results with the returned values.

```
[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"A*" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `collectionSections` property on `MPMediaQuery` to get the relevant section of your data. For the `artistsQuery`, the `title` of each `MPMediaQuerySection` represents the first letter of an artist name. Each section also has a `range`, which you could then apply to get a subarray of artist names from the `collections` array.

This will give you the `MPMediaQuerySection` for the letter *A*:

```
MPMediaQuery *allArtistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery artistsQuery];
NSArray *collectionSections = allArtistsQuery.collectionSections;
NSPredicate *artistPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", @"A"];

MPMediaQuerySection *artistSection = [[collectionSections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:artistPredicate] lastObject];
```

Then take the `range` property of that section to get a subarray of all artist collections starting with the letter *A*:

```
NSArray *collections = allArtistsQuery.collections;
NSRange arraySlice = artistSection.range;
NSArray *filteredCollections = [collections subarrayWithRange:arraySlice];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *artistCollection in filteredCollections) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[artistCollection representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]);
}
```